# convert multiple jpeg images to one compressed tiff image with wand library

Tags: python, python-2.7, imagemagick, windows-10, wand

I'm developing on **Windows10 x64** and **Python 2.7.14**

I have to collect scanned JPEG images into a single compressed TIFF file.

I tried `Pillow` image library with `libtiff` but it corrupted the resulting tiff file whichever compression algorithm I set. Without compression algorithm it produces a 100 MBs of non corrupted tiff file.

Then I found `Image Magick` command line tool and it worked well with compression. It compressed a 100 MBs uncompressed tiff file into a 7 MBs jpeg compressed tiff file.

```
magick.exe -compress jpeg *.jpg abc.tif
```

It is really hard to get permission to run a third party exe on our servers. So I decided to use it as a library in my Python application and found `Wand` library. Now the problem is that Wand library does not compress the result tiff file.

**How can I produce a compressed tiff file with Wand library?**

Below is what I end up with:

```
import os
from wand.image import Image

imagepaths = []
folder = "d:/scan/"
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".jpeg"):
        imagepaths.append(os.path.join(folder, file))

with Image() as img:
    img.sequence.extend( [ Image(filename=f, resolution=300) for f in  imagepaths] )
    img.compression = "jpeg"
    img.compression_quality = 50 # these two lines have no effect, no compression is done
    img.save(filename="d:/scan/wand_converted.tif")
    # this generates a tiff file with about 100 MBs of size
    # When I convert jpegs to tiff with magick at command line it produces a 7 MBs file
```

Comment: Just for kicks, try `img.compression="lzw"` to see if it has an effect.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you, I'll try this tomorrow and will inform you

Comment: `jpeg` compresion is relatively new in TIFFs and `lzw` was traditionally used to quite good effect. It is somewhat dependent on your image - photographic images compress better with `jpeg` but computer-generated graphics reduce pretty well under `lzw`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell no change happened, with lzw compression, tiff file is still 100 MBs. I think no compression has been applied. I am missing sth but I could not find.

Comment: I suspect Eric (@emcconville) will know the answer to this...